# Back from confirm credentials to main activity on timeout

Tags: java, android

In my application I have to navigate to PrefActivity after the user confirm his credentials, but I also want to finish this activity if user does not confirm credentials at some time and bring him back to the main screen. How can I do this?

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
Intent intent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(getString(R.string.app_name), getString(R.string.text_keyguard));

startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityMain.SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                  Thread.sleep(15000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  return;
                }
                /////////////////////////////
                //  Timeout Return Code Here
                /////////////////////////////
     }
}).start();
```

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == ActivityMain.SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead, put the timeout in your ActivityMain, and call finishActivity() from inside ActivityMain.

Comment: @Dylan I want to finish confirm credentials activity, not my app.